# Is there a way to Dynamically resize a specific element after window is created in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pysimplegui

In the below code i made the whole window very dynamic and adaptive to window resize here i want to further achieve dynamic resizing ability along the X-axis(Horizontally) for only the "--SIGNAL_FRAME--" Element on my window so when i resize the signal frame the canvas element(Element right side to the signal frame) should also resize and fit to screen

## Code to Duplicate

Python: 3.8, tkinter version: 8.6.9,
PySimpleGUI version: 4.60.4

```
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
                                               NavigationToolbar2Tk)

def repack(widget, option):
    pack_info = widget.pack_info()
    pack_info.update(option)
    widget.pack(**pack_info)

max_checkbox_count = 0
def draw_figure_w_toolbar(canvas, fig, canvas_toolbar):
    if canvas.children:
        for child in canvas.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    if canvas_toolbar.children:
        for child in canvas_toolbar.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    toolbar = Toolbar(figure_canvas_agg, canvas_toolbar)
    toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def generate_gui(cols=[]):
    menu_def = [['File', ['Open', 'Exit']]]

    # signal_list = [[check_box_btn(i)] for i in cols]
    signal_list = [[]]
    signals = [[
        sg.B('Search', k='--SEARCH--', bind_return_key=True),
        sg.InputText(
                    expand_x=True,
                     k='--SEARCH_KEY--',
                     tooltip='Enter part of your signal name to search')
                ],
               [
                   sg.Column(layout=signal_list,
                             scrollable=True,
                             expand_y=True,
                             expand_x=True,
                             k='--SIGNAL_COLUMN--',
                             )
               ],
               [
                   sg.Text(f'No. of Signals: {max_checkbox_count}',
                           k='--SIGNAL_COUNT--',
                           expand_x=True,
                           )
               ]
               ]

    layout = [
        [sg.MenubarCustom(menu_def)],
        [sg.Frame('Controls',
                  size=(None, 60),
                  expand_x=True,
                  layout=[[
                      sg.B('Report'),
                      sg.B('Exit'),
                      sg.Push(),
                      sg.Canvas(key='controls_cv')
                  ]])],
        [
            sg.pin(sg.Frame(k='--SIGNAL_FRAME--',
                     layout=signals,
                     title='Signal List',
                     expand_y=True,
                     expand_x=True,
                     size=(200, None)
                     ),
                     expand_x=True,
                     expand_y=True
            ),
            # sg.pin(
                sg.Column(
                layout=[
                    [
                        sg.Canvas(
                            key='fig_cv',
                            size=(1920/2, 1080/2),  #(W,H)
                            expand_x=True,
                            expand_y=True,
                            background_color='black')
                    ],
                ],
                expand_x=True,
                expand_y=True,
                background_color='black'),
                # expand_x=True,
                # expand_y=True
                # ),
        ],
        [
            sg.Frame(
                title="Debug",
                layout=[
                    [
                        sg.Multiline('...',
                                     expand_x=True,
                                     disabled=True,
                                     write_only=True,
                                     expand_y=True,
                                     autoscroll=True,
                                     horizontal_scroll=True,
                                     size=(None, 5),
                                     k="--DEBUG_OUT--"),
                        sg.B('Execute')
                    ],
                ],
                expand_x=True,
                # expand_y=True,  #size=(None,100)
            ),
        ]
    ]

    return layout


window = sg.Window(
    '',
    layout=generate_gui(cols=[]),
    location=(0, 0),
    resizable=True,
    finalize=True)

fig = Figure((8, 4), 100)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(10)
axs = gs.subplots(sharex=True)

draw_figure_w_toolbar(window['fig_cv'].TKCanvas, fig,
                              window['controls_cv'].TKCanvas)

# masters for parent widget, there're lot of hidden row Frames, `pin` frames, `Frame` frames and `Column` frames in the layout.

repack(window['--SIGNAL_FRAME--'].widget.master.master, {'fill':'y', 'expand':0, 'before':window['fig_cv'].widget.master.master})
repack(window["--DEBUG_OUT--"].widget.master.master.master.master, {'side':'bottom'})
repack(window['--SIGNAL_FRAME--'].widget.master.master.master, {'side':'top'})

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event.lower() == 'report':
        x = np.linspace(0, 20 * np.pi)
        y = np.sin(x) * 10
        # plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x) + 40, 1))
        axs[0].plot(x, y, '.')
        axs[1].step(x, y)
        draw_figure_w_toolbar(window['fig_cv'].TKCanvas, fig,
                              window['controls_cv'].TKCanvas)
        window.refresh()

window.close()
```

## Question

I want the ability to resize the "--SIGNAL_FRAME--" after the window is created i know that this can be achieved using Pane Element but when tried its throwing different errors for different scenarios.
Iam trying to achieve something similar to this example
https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib_Browser_Paned.py
Where you can resize the canvas element but in my case i want to resize the "--SIGNAL_FRAME--" after window is created

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear. The ```Pane``` of PySimpleGUI(the ```PanedWindow``` of Tkinter) is a container widget for resizing its child widgets manually. Are you asking on how to use the ```Pane```? Anyway, post a [mre] and debugging details.

Comment: Just remove all the `repack` code, they required only when the expand options different for those elements at the same row.